# Using gmail and phpmailer to send notification emails with limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

I started using limesurvey today itself.

I am trying to setup gmail to send me email notifications when the survey is filled. I want to notify the user and the admin both.

But it doesn't seem to work.

And most frustrating part is I cannot find the debug or error msgs anywhere.

I am on a windows limesurvey XAMPP installation.

So please let me know where can I find the debug file or the error msgs for the SMTP fail.

For testing I fill out the form myself and wait for the email but it doesn't come.

My settings for gmail are:

- smtp.gmail.com:587
- my username
- my password
- TLS
- debug onerrors
- batch value is 50

limesurvey uses phpmailer to send the emails as far as I know.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: And with debug : always (and debug=2 in config.php)

Comment: To see complete debug : you must send an token email. Just create a survey for this.

Comment: good day dear Denis Chenu 

- first of all ,many many thanks for the answer and all the ideas that you share. GREAT to hear from you - well one question left - can we do this with gmail - and can we just use the following settings of gl

email setup like so 


1. Create a survey
2. Activate particpant
3. Create a participant with our email
4. Try to send the inviation.
-
When it work : we shhould check other email.
 - what about this setup!? Love to hear from you